# Java getDate 0000/00/00 return strange value

Tags: java

Why does this happens? For the month and day, I think Java is assuming the previous valid month and day, but I don't understand why year is 2.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date result = sdf.parse("0000/00/00");

System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Output is:

```
Sun Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT 2
```

Comment: Confused what you're trying to do...

Comment: @AliGajani Probably hoping to ask a _famous_ question

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @aioobe more commonly in java is Garbage in, Exception out.  The op has simply seen something odd and trying to understand what drives the result.

Comment: @couling, the date API did ideed leave a lot of room for improvements.

Comment: This happened when displaying a report to a costumer, where the String date had the value 00000000, and it displayed on the report that strange date that we couldn't explain. So I'm trying to figure what Java is doing in it's guts ;)

Comment: @AliGajani Using one sentence you may know, another reason for asking this question was "I have an infinite curiosity for knowledge." ;)

Comment: @balizeiro..haha, nice one

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Gregorian calendar does not have year 0.

Year 0 corresponds to 1BCE (Before Common Era, also known as BC).

Because you supply 0 for the month and 0 for the day, it rolls back to the previous month and previous year.

I.e. 30-Nov-0002 BCE.

`Date#toString` does *not* include BCE / CE suffix. It would be superfluous in the vast majority of cases.

If you are going to work with dates that far back then you need to consult with an historian.

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

By default `SimpleDateFormat` tries to parse even incorrect input. You can switch this off using [`setLenient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) method:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date result = sdf.parse("0000/00/00");
```

This way you will have an exception which is probably more appropriate in your case:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "0000/00/00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at Snippet.main(Snippet.java:11)
```

Answer (score 4):

The starting point for Date would be `00010101`
ei Year - 1 , Month - Jan and Date - 1

What you have given input is `00000000`

Will start with month - 00 means `Jan  - 1` ie Dec

Day `00` mean `1 Dec - 1` ie `30th Nov`

This explains the 1st part of the output. `Sun Nov 30 00:00:00 GMT`

The year is given `00` that mean year 1 minus 1 . ie 1 BC
And as year rolls back another time for month and date its 2 BC.

Hence the year is shown as 2.