# SimpleDateFormat return all zero date

Tags: android, mysql, kotlin, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm using SimpleDateFormat to convert date/time read from phone's call log, but I got date/time in all zeros like: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'(year-month-day hour:minute:second)

I have the date/time converted into 2 formats:

```kotlin
class callReader (val context: Context)
{
    private val sdfStr = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
    private val sdfNum = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
    ....

    fun readCallLogs()
    {
        if (cursor != null) 
        {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {                    
                do 
                {
                    val phon = cursor.getString(number!!)
                    val mill = callDate?.let { cursor.getLong(it) }
                    val date = sdfStr.format(mill)
                    val ndat = sdfNum.format(mill)
                    ....
                    // constructed a data string and 
                    // save data to MySQL table with Volley
                }while (cursor.moveToNext())
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

I saved the date in 2 formats, sdfStr is 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss' for my user to read and sdfNum is to save the data as DateTime data type in MySQL table so that I can sort the date properly, thus it is converted to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', which is accepted by MySQL as a DateTime format.

The problem is, all dates returned from sdfNum are all zeros while the sdfStr returns proper date in string format:

[image]

I couldn't verify the original date/time on the phone, as it is not my phone, but rather it belongs to someone using my Application. However, the only changes made to the data is through the SimpleDateFormat object. My PHP pages only takes the data 'as is' and store them into the data table.

My problem is: Why SimpleDateFormat would return a result completely consists of zeros?

I have other users data where the clog_dnum is containing proper date/time data. This problem is from one user only.

On further thought, maybe the sdf returned an invalid date so that MySQL server is unable to process it thus all it can do is storing the data as all zeros. Either way, surely the problem comes from SimpleDateFormat - since both 'sdfStr' and 'sdfNum' are getting the date value from 'mill' (date in milliseconds)

Here is other data rows with proper clog_dnum date. Note the clog_idat (Insert Date, the date/time I saved the data) is having erroneous month of zero, this is also a problem I have face quite frequently, thus I suspect SDF is bugged. Can any one confirm that?

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Darren.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with. Also do not transfer date and time as strings between Java and MySQL. Transfer good and proper date-time objects such as `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` cannot generate `0000-00-00 00:00:00` since it is not a valid/existing date. Rather it’s the MySQL default for a missing datetime. They should have preferred `null`, though.

Comment: Also don’t store the date in human-readable format in the database. Human-readable format is for where the user reads it. Use MySQL `datetime` (or even better `timestamp`) data type and only format into the user’s preferred format in your app when you actually need to display the date and time to the user.

Comment: Related: [Java getDate 0000/00/00 return strange value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394996/java-getdate-0000-00-00-return-strange-value)

Comment: @Ole V.V.: I have a reason to save the date in human-readable format - there are 3 parties involved here: Me and the users are in same time zone, but my client, the one commissioned me to make the app, is in another time zone. I have no way to alter the client's server setting to alter the time zone, thus I have to save the date in user's phone in a human-readable date in the database, for the users to read. Thanks for the advice, I'll try them out.